# How to read the next page on API using python iterator?

Tags: python, api, iterator

There is an API that only produces one hundred results per page. I am trying to make a while loop so that it goes through all pages and takes results from all pages, but it does not work. I would be grateful if you could help me figure it out.

```
    params = dict(
    order_by='salary_desc',
    text=keyword,
    area=area,
    period=30, # days
    per_page=100,
    page = 0,
    no_magic='false',  # disable magic
    search_field='name'  # available: name, description, company_name
)
response = requests.get(
    BASE_URL + '/vacancies',
    headers={'User-Agent': generate_user_agent()},
    params=params,
)
response

items = response.json()['items']
vacancies = []
for item in items:
    vacancies.append(dict(
        id=item['id'],
        name=item['name'],
        salary_from=item['salary']['from'] if item['salary'] else None,
        salary_to=item['salary']['to'] if item['salary'] else None,
        currency = item['salary']['currency'] if item['salary'] else None,
        created=item['published_at'],
        company=item['employer']['name'],
        area = item['area']['name'],
        url=item['alternate_url']
    ))
```

I loop through the dictionary, if there is a result in the dictionary, I add +1 to the page parameter as an iterator:

```
while vacancies == True:
  params['page'] += 1
```

Result in dictionary params ['page'] = zero remains (pages in API start at zero).

When calling params after starting the loop, the result is:

```
{'area': 1,
'no_magic': 'false',
'order_by': 'salary_desc',
'page': 0,
'per_page': 100,
'period': 30,
'search_field': 'name',
'text': '"python"'}
```

Perhaps I am doing the loop incorrectly, starting from the logic that while there is a result in the dictionary, the loop must be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while vacancies == True: # 
  params['page'] += 1
```

will never evaluate to literal `True` regardless of it's contents. Python `dict`'s; even thought they are [Truthy](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/#:%7E:text=%F0%9F%94%B9%20Truthy%20Values,strings%2C%20dictionaries%2C%20sets) They aren't `True`. You need to lessen the strictness of the statement.

```
if vacancies: # is truthy if it's len > 0, falsey otherwise
    # Do something
```

Or you can explicitly check that it has content

```
if len(vacancies) > 0:
    # Do something
```

This solves the problem of how to evaluate based on an object but doesn't solve the overall logic problem.

```
for _ in vacancies:
    params["page"] += 1
    # Does something for every item in vacancies
```

What you do each loop will depend on the problem and will require another question!

fixed below

```
params = dict(
    order_by='salary_desc',
    text=keyword,
    area=area,
    period=30, # days
    per_page=100,
    page = 0,
    no_magic='false',  # disable magic
    search_field='name'  # available: name, description, company_name
)
pages = []
while True:
  params["page"] += 1
  response = requests.get(BASE_URL + '/vacancies', headers={'User-Agent': generate_user_agent()}, params=params,)
  items = response.json()['items']
  if not items:
    break
  pages.append(items) # Do it for each page
```

Make vacancies for each page

```
results = []
for page in pages:
  vacancies = []
  for item in page:
      vacancies.append(dict(
          id=item['id'],
          name=item['name'],
          salary_from=item['salary']['from'] if item['salary'] else None,
          salary_to=item['salary']['to'] if item['salary'] else None,
          currency = item['salary']['currency'] if item['salary'] else None,
          created=item['published_at'],
          company=item['employer']['name'],
          area = item['area']['name'],
          url=item['alternate_url']
      ))
  results.append(vacancies)
```

Results will be the fine list of all items.

Comment: This code if len (vacancies)> 0: goes to the next page, but does not go to the next and does not save the complete result of all pages. It gives the result only for the page that I went to, me need to collect the results of all pages.

Comment: Strange this code for i in vacancies:
    params["page"] += 1 finds a hundred pages. Although there are only five pages of results.

Comment: You could watch my colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14KddVLTyH3LkcE-LmHm7EooTYMM7b0zB?usp=sharing ?

Comment: I've modified the [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14KddVLTyH3LkcE-LmHm7EooTYMM7b0zB?usp=sharing#scrollTo=i2JxieMWfUFm) to perform the calculation per item per page and edited my answer to show updated code

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to turn on the editor mode, the results were not saved. If it's not difficult, edit it again.

Comment: Thanks, the script works well. But unfortunately it doesn't see the first zero page (pages start at zero). Please tell me how you can fix this error?

Comment: Created a separate question for this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65358754/the-iteration-loop-is-not-working-properly-for-api?noredirect=1#comment115552668_65358754 . I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Edited the Collab to reflect the new questions solution

Answer (score 0):

`vacancies` is never `True`.
If you want to test on the boolean value of "vacancies" you could use `bool(vacancies)`.
But with Python, you can use

```
while vacancies:
  # some code logic
```

This way, Python will auto cast to bool your list.
If your list as something inside (`len(your_list) > 0`), `bool(your_list)` evaluatues to `True`, else it's `False`.

Also, instead of using `dict()`, you could write your dict this way:

```
params = {
    'order_by': 'salary_desc',
    'text':keyword,
    'area': area,
    'period': 30, # days
    'per_page': 100,
    'page': 0,
    'no_magic': 'false',  # disable magic
    'search_field': 'name'  # available: name, description, company_name
}
```

which is more pythonic.

Comment: Could you show the response of your api request?
I didn't see that the logic isn't good on this one, you will indeed get an endless loop

Comment: I am making a request on google colab. He doesn’t give an answer, it just spins around in the cell. You can see my colab at the link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14KddVLTyH3LkcE-LmHm7EooTYMM7b0zB?usp=sharing