# The iteration loop is not working properly for API

Tags: python, api, iterator, iteration

There is an API that only produces one hundred results per page. I am trying to make a while loop so that it goes through all pages and takes results from all pages, but it does not work properly.

This script goes through the pages:

```
params = dict(
    order_by='salary_desc',
    text=keyword,
    area=area,
    period=30, # days
    per_page=100,
    page = 0,
    no_magic='false',  # disable magic
    search_field='name'  # available: name, description, company_name
)
pages = []
while True:
  params["page"] += 1
  response = requests.get(BASE_URL + '/vacancies', headers={'User-Agent': generate_user_agent()}, params=params,)
  items = response.json()['items']
  if not items:
    break
  pages.append(items) # Do it for each page
response
```

At startup:

```
params
```

```
{'area': 1,
 'no_magic': 'false',
 'order_by': 'salary_desc',
 'page': 5,
 'per_page': 100,
 'period': 30,
 'search_field': 'name',
 'text': '"python"'}
```

He sees five pages.

When I look at the variable after execution:

```
len(pages)
4
```

He only sees four pages.

If I understood correctly, he does not see the zero page (pages in the api start at zero).

Please tell me how you can fix this error?

Complete script in colab at this link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14KddVLTyH3LkcE-LmHm7EooTYMM7b0zB?usp=sharing

Comment: The code increments page before fetching, so you never do a fetch on page 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand how to fix this so that the page starts at zero.

Comment: Move the page increment to the bottom of the for loop, instead of the top.

Comment: I think you are wrong. When the params variable is called, it will output the correct number of five pages. But when we look at the variable with the finished result pages, it produces four pages. I think there is a logical error here, but I do not understand why he only adds four out of five pages.

Comment: page starts at zero and is incremented to 1 before making the request, so page 0 is never fetched.  I don't know how to explain the problem any simpler than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing the page prior to grabbing the response. Just reorder like so.

```
while True:
  response = requests.get(BASE_URL + '/vacancies', headers={'User-Agent': generate_user_agent()}, params=params,)
  items = response.json()['items']
  if not items:
    break
  pages.append(items) # Do it for each page
  params["page"] += 1
```